# Echo off in Jenkins Console Output

Tags: jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, echo, android-keystore

I'm following [guideline](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#configureSigning) how to sign Android apk with Jenkins. I have parametrized Jenkins job with KSTOREPWD and KEYPWD. A part of Jenkins' job configuration (Build->Execute shell) is to take those parameters and store them as environment variables:

```
export KSTOREPWD=${KSTOREPWD}
export KEYPWD=${KEYPWD}
...
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The problem is when the build is over anybody can access the build "Console Output" and see what passwords were entered; part of that output:

```
08:06:57 + export KSTOREPWD=secretStorePwd
08:06:57 + KSTOREPWD=secretStorePwd
08:06:57 + export KEYPWD=secretPwd
08:06:57 + KEYPWD=secretPwd
```

So I'd like to suppress echo before output from `export` commands and re-enable echo after `export` commands.

Comment: a detailed answer over on superuser: [suppress-execution-trace-for-echo-command](https://superuser.com/a/1141026/279136)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

By default, Jenkins launches *Execute Shell* script with `set -x`. This causes all commands to be echoed

You can type `set +x` before any command to temporary override that behavior. Of course you will need `set -x` to start showing them again.

You can override this behaviour for the whole script by putting the following at the top of the build step:
`#!/bin/bash +x`

Comment: Incidentally I found `#!/bin/bash` also worked for me.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent `set +x` itself from being printed in the "temporary" approach?

Answer (score 38):

Here is an example of how to write the `sh` parameter in `Jenkinsfile` with no output in a more secure way, as suggested in [official documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/). The `set +x` does the main magic as has been written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26803326/2924596).

> The single-quotes will
>   cause the secret to be expanded by the shell as an environment
>   variable. The double-quotes are potentially less secure as the secret
>   is interpolated by Groovy, and so typical operating system process
>   listings (as well as Blue Ocean, and the pipeline steps tree in the
>   classic UI) will accidentally disclose it:

Insecure, wrong usage:

```
node {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    sh /* WRONG! */ """
      set +x
      curl -H 'Token: $TOKEN' https://some.api/
    """
  }
}
```

Correct usage ✅:

```
node {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -H 'Token: $TOKEN' https://some.api/
    '''
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need for 'set +x' in your shell, the withCredentials block will ensure that passowrd is not printed to the console, replacing any output of the credential with '****'.

Comment: @jrodriguez for many cases it does. Same time this answer is for the rest of the cases when it's not. :)

Comment: Doesn't the Token part need to be in double quotes?

Answer (score 3):

In your specific situation (using gradle and jenkins) you could also use a Password Parameter, using [Gradle's pattern for environment variables](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) (`ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_prop)`. Gradle will then set a `prop`property on your project.

In your case this would look something like this

[image]

And you can use it in your `gradle.properties` like this

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(KEYSTORE)
        storePassword KSTOREPWD
        keyAlias ALIAS
        keyPassword KEYPWD
    }
}
```

BTW - I recommend using the [credentials binding plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) for `KEYSTORE`
[image]