# Hide command executed, only show output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to hide jenkins sh execute command in pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Load Lib') {
            steps {
                sh "ls -al /"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current result:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Load Lib)
[Pipeline] sh
[Test] Running shell script
+ ls -al /
```

I want to hide **Running shell script ls -al /** command in output.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echo off in Jenkins Console Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797219/echo-off-in-jenkins-console-output)

Comment: 5 year and  sh("set +x\n" + "ls -la") for every single bash line? I think is in this method but I don't see any kind of logger https://github.com/jenkinsci/shell-script-scm-plugin/blob/d35002a554f8e95301342c43f30e9a21a30a5c69/src/main/java/org/jvnet/hudson/plugins/ssscm/ShellScriptSCM.java#L306

Answer (score 36):

This is definitely related to [Echo off in Jenkins Console Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797219/echo-off-in-jenkins-console-output)

For pipeline, what this means is:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Load Lib') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    set +x
                    //commands to be echoed off
                    ls -al
                    set -x 
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`'''` indicates a multi line command. `set +x` turns off command echoing, and `set -x` turns it back on again.

Comment: If you need to interpolate ${VARIABLE}s, you can substitute a triple double quote: """

Comment: This is just excluding command from console, but If I hover on Jenkins Pipeline stage log from UI, then it still shows command

Answer (score 1):

You can override this behaviour for the whole script by putting the following at the top of the build step:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
```

Comment: Can you mention how to add this line in groovy? like, sh(script:"#!/bin/bash +x"??

Comment: This will just hide command from console, but if you hover on the pipeline stage UI logs, then you can still see the command