# Jenkins Credential plugin to resolve username and password with @ correctly using Pipeline groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to connect to github using Jenkins Credential plugin

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: gitCredential, passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
        sh("git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@stash.abc.com:656/rad/abl/optical.git --tags")
    }
```

I am trying to push into Git, but it is failing with the below error, since the password contains @. Since there is no way we could urlEncode on the password obtained from the Jenkins credential plugin. I am looking for a way to resolve the username and password correctly.

```
[Tagging] Running shell script
+ git push 'https://****:****@stash.abc.com:656/rad/abl/optical.git' --tags
fatal: unable to access 'https://****:ZxmP*K@v6iO/?w4ms@stash.abc.com:656/rad/abl/optical.git': Couldn't resolve host 'v6iO'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
```

Any input would be helpful.

Thanks !

Comment: Oh special chars in password of credentials seems to be a common annoying issue. If you set the origin to your push URL and use a git credential helper, does that give you any mileage on it? I haven't tried this so don't feel I can put it as an answer. There are some details here worth looking at: https://alanedwardes.com/blog/posts/git-username-password-environment-variables/

Comment: Thanks @macg33zr , that certainly did help :)

Answer (score 2):

This question was answered in a [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55970749/1252947). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107353/1252947) describes how to use the URLEncoder command to encode the special characters in the password.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: gitCredential, passwordVariable: "GIT_PASSWORD", usernameVariable: "GIT_USERNAME")]) {
    script {
        env.URL_ENCODED_GIT_PASSWORD=URLEncoder.encode(GIT_PASSWORD, "UTF-8")
    }
        sh "git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${URL_ENCODED_GIT_PASSWORD}@stash.abc.com:656/rad/abl/optical.git --tags"
}
```

I think there is just one problem with this solution. After you have encoded the password jenkins will output its value without the mask (****). One possible solution to this problem is to [disable the command echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607994/1252947). Another solution that I have seen is to [use the MaskPasswords plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680266/1252947), but I don't know if that works because I wasn't able to test it.