# Git push using jenkins credentials from declarative pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-push

I'm using jenkins pipeline (declarative synthax) and I want to push a commit to my remote repository.

Is there any way to accomplish this using the git plugin?
Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID}", passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
                        sh "git add ${BRANCH_RENAME}.bundle"
                        sh "echo ${GIT_USERNAME}|||||||${GIT_PASSWORD}"
                        sh "git tag -a backup -m 'Backup branch ${BRANCH} from vega-salesforce to vega-salesforce-backup' "
                        sh('git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@${GIT_URL_WITHOUT_HTTPS} --tags')
                    }
```

But it does'nt works. 
I got the following error:`

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://****:****@myrepositoryurl/mygitgroup/salesforce-backup/': Could not resolve host: ****:clear_password_here; Name or service not known
```

Could anyone help please?
I though the issue comes from the special characters present in my password but I'm not sure.

Comment: This would probably be easier with the Git Pipeline Plugin.

Comment: There are not git plugin for push inside jenkins pipeline. Are there?

Comment: We solved the issue by url encoding the password. The problem was that the GIT_PASSWORD contains specials characters that should be encoded

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We finally figure it out.
The problem was simply that we have special characters in our password which break out the url.

Here is the working code:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: env.GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID, usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASS')]) {
                    script {
                        env.encodedPass=URLEncoder.encode(PASS, "UTF-8")
                    }
                    sh 'git clone https://${USER}:${encodedPass}@${GIT_URL} ${DIR} -b ${BRANCH}'
                    sh 'git add .'
                    sh 'git commit -m "foobar" '
                    sh 'git push'
                }
```

Comment: I think there is just one problem with this solution. After you have encoded the password jenkins will output its value without the mask (****). One possible solution to this problem is to [disable the command echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607994/1252947). Another solution that I have seen is to [use the MaskPasswords plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680266/1252947), but I don't know it that works because I wasn't able to test it.

Comment: @PedroPinheiro , thanks you to point that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use username:password for connecting to git repo in script.

You should use ssh key. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38784011/1573395) for more information

Comment: I cannot use ssh because of corp restriction.

Comment: We solved the issue by url encoding the password. The problem was that the GIT_PASSWORD contains specials characters that should be encoded