# Suppress sensitive information from Jenkins logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to suppress some sensitive information displayed in the logs.

Code:

```
    pipeline {
    parameters {
    string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'pki_client_cacert_password', trim: true)
    string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'db_url', trim: true)
    }
    stages {
        stage('DeployToDev') {
                steps {
                    script{
                        env.artifacts = sh(
                        returnStdout: true, 
                        script: "/var/lib/jenkins/python_jobs/venv/bin/python3 /var/lib/jenkins/python_jobs/encrypter_creds.py --db_url=${env.db_url} --pki_client_cacert_password='${env.pki_client_cacert_password}'"
                        )
                    }

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
+ /var/lib/jenkins/python_jobs/venv/bin/python3 /var/lib/jenkins/python_jobs/encrypter_creds.py --db_url=<hide this from jenkins logs> '--pki_client_cacert_password=<hide this from jenkins logs>'
```

Answer (score 2):

First option is to set it as environment var:

```
withEnv(["MYSECRET=${params.pki_client_cacert_password}", 
         "MYURL=${env.db_url}"]) {
    env.artifacts = sh(
        returnStdout: true, 
        script: '.. python3 .. encrypter_creds.py --db_url=$MYURL ' +
            ' --pki_client_cacert_password=$MYSECRET'
)
```

Note the single quotes around the command to prevent any Groovy string interpolation.

Second option is to save something like `pki_client_cacert_password` (which hopefully doesn't change much) into Jenkins Credentials Store and use it `withCredentials`:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(
  credentialsId: 'MY_PKI_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS',
  passwordVariable: 'DB_URL',
  usernameVariable: 'PKI_USER')]) {
  env.artifacts = sh(
        returnStdout: true, 
        script: '.. python3 .. encrypter_creds.py --db_url=$DB_URL' +
            ' --pki_client_cacert_password=$PKI_PASSWORD'

}
```

You can also roll your own third option, e.g. by writing the info you need into a file and modifying your script to read the parameters from that file.

Comment: Install mask passwords plugin. In some cases jenkins could show creds in job's output, mask passwords plugin will prevent it.

Comment: @DmitriyTarasevich that plugin does not seem to support pipelines.

Comment: This plugin processes output, it doesn't care about type of job. If you have negative experience with the plugin, please share.

Comment: @DmitriyTarasevich I find it hard to understand what do I need to put in my pipeline to explain to that plugin what contributes a "password".

Answer (score 1):

I have added @MaratC suggestion however that did not help much, so I ended up adding `set +x` and `set -x` more so this question was related to
[Echo off in Jenkins Console Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797219/echo-off-in-jenkins-console-output)
which worked as expected

```
            script{
               withEnv(["ENV_PKI_CLIENT_CACERT_PASSWORD=${params.pki_client_cacert_password}", "ENV_DB_URL=${params.db_url}"]) {
                    env.artifacts = sh(
                        returnStdout: true, 
                        script: """
                            set +x
                            /var/lib/jenkins/python_jobs/venv/bin/python3 /var/lib/jenkins/python_jobs/encrypter_creds.py --db_url=${ENV_DB_URL} --pki_client_cacert_password='${ENV_PKI_CLIENT_CACERT_PASSWORD}'
                            set -x
                            """
                        )           
            }
        }
```

Jenkins output

```
 + set +x
[Pipeline] .....
[Pipeline] .....
```